# How to provide infinite animations through AnimationPlayer or AnimationReferenceMetadata (alternatives wanted)

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have a `AnimationPlayer` defined animation according a specified `AnimationReferenceMetadata` definition.

Some thing like this :

```
const base: AnimationMetadata[] = [
  style({
    opacity: `{{startOpacity}}`
  }),
  animate(
    `{{duration}} {{delay}} {{easing}}`,
    style({
      opacity: `{{endOpacity}}`
    })
  )
];

const fadeIn: AnimationReferenceMetadata = animation(base, {
  params: {
    delay: "0s",
    duration: "350ms",
    easing: EaseOut.sine,
    endOpacity: 1,
    startOpacity: 0
  }
});
```

I have a `directive` to play a animation upon interaction.
This `directive`is using a `Animation` class to build and play the animation according the specified `AnimationReferenceMetadata`.

```
export class Animation extends BehaviorManager {

  private _player: AnimationPlayer;
  private _isInfinite: boolean = false;

  constructor(meta: AnimationReferenceMetadata, infinte:boolean = false, public _el: ElementRef,private _builder: AnimationBuilder) {
    super();

    const animation: AnimationFactory = this._builder.build(meta);
    this._isInfinite = infinte;
    this._player = animation.create(this._el.nativeElement);
  }

  public play() {
    this._player.onDone(() => {
      if(this._isInfinite){
        this.reset();
        this.play();
      }
    });
    this._player.play();
  }

  public reset() {
    this._player.reset();
  }
}
```

I want to infinite play the animation.

It seems the `animation-iteration-count` (infinite) is not supported. Or maybe I'm using it wrong.

Using the `onDone` callback I can reset and replay the `AnimationPlayer`.

**The infinite animation loop works.**

**I'm looking for a better way to infinite this animation. 
Any suggestions or help?**

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: No, in the end i've used the above ...